Excess waiting time given two exponential variables
Suppose that there are two patients that arrive on time to a clinic. The time that each patient takes with the doctor is distributed according to an exponential and the expectation of that is 0.5 hours. If the patient one arrives at 0 and two at 0.5 hours then the expect time the patient two will wait is:
\begin{align}
\int_{30}^\infty (t-30)\frac{e^{-t/30}}{30}dt
&=\left[-te^{-t/30}+30e^{-t/30}\right]_{30}^\infty +\int_0^\infty e^{-t/30}dt\\
&=30e^{-1}-30e^{-1}-\left[30e^{-t/30}\right]_{30}^\infty\\
&=30e^{-1}
\end{align}
right? They are telling me the answer is 30 and the professor is a phd so...

You use minutes in your integral calculation but the problem was formulated with hours. It's probably best to pick just one of them.

I think your calculation is correct. Below is an alternate approach that leverages the memorylessness property of the exponential distribution to avoid integrating by parts.
30 minutes would be the expected waiting time of patient two if they arrived at the same time as patient one (at time $0$), so it does not make sense that their expected waiting time is the same if they arrive 30 minutes after patient $1$. Maybe double check that the problem statement is correct?

Alternate solution:
When $T \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda)$, the memorylessness property implies that the distribution of "$T-c$ conditioned on the event $T > c$" is also $\text{Exponential}(\lambda)$.
Thus,
\begin{align}
E[\max\{T - c, 0\}]
= E[T - c \mid T > c] P(T > c) + 0 \cdot P(T \le c)
= \frac{1}{\lambda} P(T > c)
= \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda c}.
\end{align}
Plugging in $\lambda = 1/30$ and $c = 30$ yields $30e^{-1}$.

This assumes that the "clock" for patient two starts when patient one arrives, but I think it's just as reasonable to assume that the expected wait time for a given patient is based on when they arrive and not someone else. In which case patient one is just a distraction  and all that matters is that patient two's expected wait time is indeed 30 minutes. But that'd be a weird way to phrase the problem.

Both OP and I are defining Patient Two's waiting time as the time between their arrival and the start of their appointment. If Patient One is finished by the time Patient Two arrives, then Patient Two does not have to wait at all; otherwise they have to wait for Patient One to finish. This is why we have a $\max{T-30, 0}$ in our answers, where $T$ is the length of Patient One's visit. I don't quite understand your comment but it seems you are counting the time until the end of Patient Two's appointment, not the beginning. @Semiclassical

What they are saying is that the solution is the expectation of t-30 wrt the distribution of the second arrival time  That is to say I assumed by the time the first patient arrived there were no other patients being seen. But they assumed there was another patient, the patient 0 already waiting. I think they are just terrible at communication. So many other problems they make are like this. They love making  hard problems that rely on paying close attention to badly posed exercises
